# Seleccionar múltiples filas y Actualizar sus valores SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

**ACTUALIZADO**

Ok aquí tengo una lista de usuarios con sus ID y el ID patrocinador.
En mi base de datos es mas grande ya que contiene fechas correo nombre y demás datos del usuario, Así que solo coloque lo que me interesa para terminar mi proyecto.

```
        ID          Status    IDpatrocinador
1    765810095      activo      123456789
2    463913563     inactivo     765810095
3    102195308      activo      463913563
4    091299283     inactivo     102195308
5    701757563      activo      091299283
6    262313912     inactivo     701757563
7    779891896      activo      262313912
8    463913563     inactivo     779891896
9    796540095      activo      463913563
```

**NOTA:** No existen los números del 1 al 9 en mi base de datos, solo los puse para que se guiaran.

Bueno. Lo que intento hacer es:
El numero 1 activo es el patrocinador del numero 2 que esta inactivo, el 2 del 3, etc. Bueno hasta ahí vamos bien.

SI un usuario esta inactivo ej. el numero 2, tomare el ID patrocinador y lo colocare en el ID patrocinador del 3, quedando el 3 así.

```
3    102195308      activo      765810095
```

Porque el 3 tenia al ID patrocinador del 2 que ahora esta inactivo.

Entonces al final quedara todo así.

```
        ID          Status    IDpatrocinador
1    765810095      activo      123456789
2    463913563     inactivo     765810095
3    102195308      activo      765810095
4    091299283     inactivo     102195308
5    701757563      activo      102195308
6    262313912     inactivo     701757563
7    779891896      activo      701757563
8    463913563     inactivo     779891896
9    796540095      activo      779891896
```

En este ejemplo use un usuario patrocinado para cada patrocinador, pero el patrocinador puede tener múltiples patrocinados, ejemplo:

```
        ID          Status    IDpatrocinador
1    765810095     inactivo     123456789
2    741852896      activo      765810095
3    321654852      activo      765810095
4    852715671      activo      765810095
```

Por lo que debería quedar así:

```
        ID          Status    IDpatrocinador
1    765810095     inactivo     123456789
2    741852896      activo      123456789
3    321654852      activo      123456789
4    852715671      activo      123456789
```

Comment: Yo el primer select lo guardaría en una tabla temporal y luego, cuando ya tengas el IdPatrocinador, haría un Update con el join de la tabla temporal.

Comment: Me podrías dar un ejemplo por favor ya que sólo me toma y actualiza una fila o me coloca el mimo IDpatrocinador en las todas las filas solicitadas al principio

Comment: Si, estoy creando la respuesta, 2 minutos y la tienes :)

Comment: @OrielC., ¿podrías modificar la pregunta aportando el dataset (phpMyAdmin/Exportar) para poder probar la solución antes de enviarla?

Comment: Lo que necesitas a fin de cuentas es refrescar una tabla con la información de tu base de datos en un sitio web? Si es así, te recomendaría investigar el uso de JQuery/AJAX. Conlleva el uso de Javascript y PHP, pero si tienes base de ello puedo ofrecer una respuesta clara.

Comment: "*Si $Status es = 'inactivo' en EJ: 2 filas de las 3 de arriba*", Te refieres al estatus del ¿patrocinador o patrocinado?.  Dices que dos de las tres filas de arriba, pero las tres tienen 'activo'.

Comment: Trato de explicarme simple. Un usuario tiene su ID y IDpatrocinador, SI su patrocinador ha pasado 6 meses y no cumplió con con algunos requisitos quedara inactivo y en el usuario patrocinado de este sera actualizada el IDpatrocinador por la IDpatrocinador del inctivo. Entonces este inactivo ya no tendra patrocinados.

Comment: Tienes sentencias contradictorias y faltas de ortografía, considera la diferencia entre "éste, este y esté" sin acento es un punto cardinal.

Comment: ¿Cómo es la relación patrocinado-patrocinador (Uno a uno, Uno a muchos ó Muchos a uno)?
¿Cómo distingo a un patrocinado en la tabla users?
¿Cómo distingo a un patrocinador en la tabla users?

Comment: Creo que deberías ser más claro ya que es un poco confuso como lo explicas, podrías mostrar la estructura de tus tablas y con eso seria mucho más simple decirte como realizarlo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haciendo self-join:

```
UPDATE users u
  INNER JOIN users p
    ON    p.ID = u.IDpatrocinador
      AND p.Status = 'inactivo'
  SET u.IDpatrocinador = p.IDpatrocinador;
```

Donde `u` son los patrocinados y `p` los patrocinadores.

Comment: Exacto lo que necesitaba. Pero el problema es que si existen 2 inactivos tengo ejecutar 2 veces la acción, ó 3, 4, etc. como podría hacer esto con una sola ejecución? y así buscar hasta que el patrocinador sea activo.

Comment: @OrielC. te refiere a que tendria que ir agrupado?

Comment: Hay otras opciones pero implicarían procedimientos almacenados ó consultas dinámicas. En términos de código es lo mas simple, lo puedes poner en un `while` en php hasta que *affected rows* sea cero.

Comment: @Sal Gracias, quedo perfecto

Answer (score 7):

Yo lo que haría sería lo siguiente. Crearía una tabla temporal y guardaría los resultados de la primera consulta.

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE tablaTemp(IDPersonal INT, Status VARCHAR(50), Idpatrocinador INT, Date DATE)";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$sql = "INSERT INTO tablaTemp SELECT IDpersonal, Status, IDpatrocinador, Date FROM users WHERE Status = 'activo'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Haces lo que tengas que hacer y, al final, el update lo atacas directamente a la tabla temporal

```
UPDATE users, tablaTemp,
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = tablaTemp. IDPersonal
SET camposAActualizar
WHERE condicion

$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

La idea sería esta.

Y cuando termines, acuerdate de borrar la tabla para que no pete si vuelves a hacer lo mismo en el futuro.

```
DROP TABLE tablaTemp;
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: La verdad creo que me dejas igual por que yo necesito la parte para actualizar tomando el valor de patrocinador al patrocinado y esto sería para mutiples usuarios al mismo tiempo. Entonces sería agrupar varias filas y tomar los valores diferentes de sus patrocinadores y integrarlos al mismo tiempo esto sería cada 10 minutos porque lo pienso integrar en un cron-job

Answer (score 7):

Voy a darte un ejemplo de como lo hice una vez y espero te ayude. En mi caso tenia que cambiar los codigo de barra de productos.

Lo primero que use es el operador `IN` que permite incluir varios valores en una instrucción `WHERE`.

```
WHERE nombre_columna IN ('valor1','valor2', ... )
```

De esta manera listaba todos los `id` asi podia hacer el cambio de correspondiente. En mi caso, vuelvo de reiterar, el cliente ingresaba a un producto y hacia el cambio de codigo de barra.

```
<?php
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE prodcode = '".$code."'"); 
// en tu caso llamaria a todos los activos

while ($fila = $sql->fetch()) {

$nuevocode = "099145798665425";
$sqlc = "UPDATE productos SET codebarra = '".$nuevocode."' WHERE id IN ('".$fila['id']."')";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlc);                                   
$stmt->execute();
}
?>
```

En `WHERE id IN ('".$fila['id']."')";` `IN` toma toda fila `id` para hacer el cambio.

Bueno, espero haberte ayudado!